# Normalization by a subgroup implies normalization of its center?

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups

Let $A$ and $B$ be two subgroups of $G$. Is it always true that if $A$ normalizes $B$ then $A$ normalizes $Z(B)$, the center of $B$ ? 
I am uncontering this argument in a proof and I am wondering if this is always the case or if it is using some particular hypothesis of the proof.

Comment: The centralizer of $B$ is a normal subgroup of the normalizer of $B.$  So, yes this is always true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your situation is as follows: $A \subseteq N_G(B)$. It is obvious that $Z(B) \subseteq N_G(B)$. Now by definition, any *normal* subgroup of $N_G(B)$ is normalized by any subgroup of $N_G(B)$. So you have to prove that $Z(B)$ is indeed normal in $N_G(B)$.

Observe that $Z(B) \text{ char } B \unlhd N_G(B)$ ($Z(B)$ is a *[characteristic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_subgroup)* subgroup in $N_G(B)$, that is, fixed by any automorphism of $N_G(B)$; and by definition $B$ is normal in its own normalizer), and this implies (apply a well-known transitivity rule: $U \text{ char } V \unlhd W \implies U \unlhd W$) that $Z(B) \unlhd N_G(B)$.

Hence, $A \subseteq N_G(Z(B))$. The argument works for any characteristic subgroup of $B$, so for example the commutator subgroup $B'$.

Somewhat easier approach: $C_G(B) \unlhd N_G(B)$ and $B \unlhd N_G(B)$, hence $Z(B)= B \cap C_G(B)$ is normal in $N_G(B)$.